# Google Map Direction show all waypoints on mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-apps, directions

I am using Google Maps Direction Api to create a Route with about 16 Waypoints excluding Origin and Destination

In the Google Maps Direction Api everything is showing fine, 16 Waypoints + Origin and Destination as a route.

Now I want to send this route to a mobile phone / tablet so that people can use that route.
For that I am building my own URL with the help of Google URL Api

The problem is that google maps is limiting the Webmap/app with 9 Waypoints so i can only get Origin+Destination+9 Waypoints instead of the 16 Waypoints.

Is there any way to force google to display every waypoint?

example link: [link](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=Bundesrechenzentrum%20GmbH,%20Hintere%20Zollamtsstra%C3%9Fe,%20Wien,%20Austria&destination=Bundesrechenzentrum%20GmbH,%20Hintere%20Zollamtsstra%C3%9Fe,%20Wien,%20Austria&travelmode=driving&waypoints=Donauzentrum%2c+Wagramer+Stra%c3%9fe%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cDonauturm%2c+Donauturmstra%c3%9fe%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cJohanniter+N%c3%96-Wien+Gesundheits-+und+soziale+Dienste+mildt%c3%a4tige+GmbH%2c+Herbeckstra%c3%9fe%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cLeopold+Museum%2c+Museumsplatz%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cNaschmarkt%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cMargareteng%c3%bcrtel%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cWienerbergstra%c3%9fe+38%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cRosenh%c3%bcgelstra%c3%9fe+35%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cSch%c3%b6nbrunn+Palace%2c+Sch%c3%b6nbrunner+Schlo%c3%9fstra%c3%9fe%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cAuhofcenter%2c+Albert-Schweitzer-Gasse%2c+Vienna%2c+Austria%7cSalzburg%2c+Austria%7cHTL+M%c3%b6dling%2c+Technikerstra%c3%9fe%2c+M%c3%b6dling%2c+Austria%7cHTL+Wien+10%2c+Ettenreichgasse%2c+Wien-Favoriten%2c+Austria%7cFlughafen+Wien+(VIE)%2c+Wien-Flughafen%2c+Schwechat%2c+Austria%7cRotes+Kreuz+Schwechat%2c+Bruck+Hainburger-Stra%c3%9fe%2c+Schwechat%2c+Austria%7cBundesrechenzentrum+GmbH%2c+Hintere+Zollamtsstra%c3%9fe%2c+Wien%2c+Austria%7c)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible. As per [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action):

> The number of waypoints allowed varies by the platform where the link
>   opens, with up to three waypoints supported on mobile browsers, and a
>   maximum of nine waypoints supported otherwise.

However, there is a feature request to allow more than 9 waypoints in Maps URLs in Google's issue tracker. You can view it and star it to get updates on it:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64921958

Hope this helps!